# combine multiple csv file having different headers into 1

Tags: shell, file, unix

I am new to shellscript. I am trying to combine multiple csv file having different headers into 1 files.
e.g

filename- file1

```
month_id name address
201701 aaa   bbb
201703 axl   cccc
```

filename- file2

```
month_id phone location
201701  2342323232 AUS
201702  2343243243 UK
```

output required--4 records.

```
month_id name address phone location
201701 aaa   bbb
201703 axl   cccc
201701                 2342323232 AUS
201702                 2343243243 UK
```

Need help to get command for getting output. Your help is highly appreciate.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179590/merge-two-csvfiles-by-column-header

Comment: Thanks for your response but this one doesnot give the result i am expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this one doesnot give the result i am expecting result same as outer join in query, value having matching header name.